# Session variable value changes between page processing somehow

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I have a script that processes a search query.  The results are returned with a sortable header, so clicking on the Lot # column title would sort the results by the lot # ASC.  However, if you had already sorted it ASC (which this is stored in a session variable), it will change it to sort it by the lot # DESC (and update that session variable).

All of this works perfectly, so long as thumbnails are not included in the search results.  When I do include them (which all that does is change the search query to include the image path, then output an image for the image column), it all breaks.  Here is what happens:

When the page loads, I `response.write(Session["sort"])` to see how I am sorting (ASC or DESC).

If a column header is clicked, I check to see if the new "order by" column was already the "order by" column (also stored in a session variable, `Session["orderby"]`).

If it was not previously set as the order by variable, it sets the sort session variable to ASC and sets the order by session variable to the column name.

If it was previously set as the order by variable, it checks to see what the current sort session variable equals.  If it equals ASC, then it sets the sort session variable to DESC and the order by session variable stays the same.  If it equals DESC, it sets the sort session variable to ASC and the order by variable remains the same.

This part actually still works to.  The problem is that at the end of processing the page, I again `response.write(Session["sort"])` to see what the variable has been set to.  This is the very last thing that happens before the page loads to the screen.  So remember, the very first thing that happens when the page is hit is it prints out the sort session variable, and the very last thing it does is prints out the variable again.

So, when images are included in the page, clicking one column will cause it to sort either ASC or DESC (depending on which column I click on, as it seems to alternate with every-other column).  So lets say the column I clicked caused the first `response.write(Session["sorty"])` to be blank (since it's not set yet), and the second to print ASC.  When I click the column again, the first will print DESC (which should be ASC since absolutely nothing is changed between the last one printed and the first one printed), and the second again prints ASC.

So somehow, the session variable is being changed between page loads when there is absolutely no page processing between the last print and the first print.  (And on every-other column, it's reversed, showing up ASC at the top, and DESC at the bottom every single time.)  Again, this works perfectly without the images.

Here's the only code with the thumbnail include script in it:

```
    if (Session["incThumb"] != null)
    {
        resultText += "<table style=\"width:100%;\">\n<tr style=\"font-weight:bold;text-align:left;\">\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">Thumb</th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_id\">Item ID</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=item_title\">Title</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_lot\">Lot</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_cs_txt_id\">Consignor ID</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblMcat.mcat_name\">Master Category</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblCat.cat_name\">Category</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_est_lo\">Low Est.</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_est_hi\">High Est.</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_reserve\">Reserve</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_status\">Status</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_pr\">Hammer Price</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblMailList.mail_ID\">Bidder ID</a></th>\n</tr>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        resultText += "<table style=\"width:100%;\">\n<tr style=\"font-weight:bold;text-align:left;\">\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_id\">Item ID</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=item_title\">Title</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_lot\">Lot</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_cs_txt_id\">Consignor ID</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblMcat.mcat_name\">Master Category</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblCat.cat_name\">Category</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_est_lo\">Low Est.</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_est_hi\">High Est.</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_reserve\">Reserve</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_status\">Status</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblItem.item_pr\">Hammer Price</a></th>\n<th style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a style=\"font-weight:bold; font-color:#000000;\" href=\"searchResults.aspx?page=" + page + "&orderBy=tblMailList.mail_ID\">Bidder ID</a></th>\n</tr>\n";
    }
```

Then just below this, I also account for it when printing out the SQL results, which is (in English), if the session variable for including thumbnails is not null, include the extra table cell for thumbnails and add in the image.

Needless to say, this one has me stumped.  I would appreciate any and all responses/comments.  Let me know if you want to see anymore code.

**EDIT**

Here's the response.write code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["sort"] + " 1<br/>");
    string orderBy = "";

    base.SubNavItems.Add("Search Home", "searchHome.aspx");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["page"]))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["orderBy"])){
            orderBy = Request.QueryString["orderBy"].ToString();
        }
        get_page(Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"].ToString()), orderBy);
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$save"]))
    {
        click_search();
    }

    Response.Write(Session["sort"] + " 1<br/>");
}
```

So because page is always set in the column headers, the `get_page()` method is called when I sort a column.  `orderBy` is set through the query string and passed along to the method `protected void get_page(Int32 page, String orderBy)` which is what contains the below code.  At the end of that method is also a `Response.Write(Session["sort"] + " 2<br/>");` line which is the last thing that method does.  No other method runs at this point.  Also, I just printed out the sort variable from the .aspx page and got the same result as the last print out of the variable that the .aspx.cs page prints (which is then different from the first one printed the next time).

I figure I'll go ahead and add the logic to the whole order by/sort:

```
    if (Session["orderBy"] != null)
    {
        if (Session["orderBy"].ToString() == orderBy)
        {
            if (Session["sort"].ToString() == "ASC")
            {
                Session["sort"] = "DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                Session["sort"] = "ASC";
            }
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
        {
            Session["sort"] = "ASC";
            Session["orderBy"] = orderBy;
        }
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
    {
        Session["sort"] = "ASC";
        Session["orderBy"] = orderBy;
    }
    else
    {
        Session["sort"] = "ASC";
        Session["orderBy"] = "tblItem.item_id";
    }
```

Comment: is `sorty` instead of `sort` a typo, or did I miss something ? (Just happening on one place). By the way, terrible spaghetti

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus No, that was in the actual code (which I just fixed, thanks), but fixing it did not fix this issue.  Thanks for the catch though.

Comment: How are you calling your last block of code? It sounds like you could be calling it once _before_ `Page_Load`, and once _during_ `Page_Load`.

Comment: @Rawling I'll update my question.

Comment: "the last line that is processed:" - is that the last line to be processed, or just the last line of `Page_Load`? `Page_Load` is just one of many events that occur during the page lifecycle in ASP.Net.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just updated my question, but there is one at the last line of the `Page_Load` as well as the last one of the method which populates the table.  So it's the last thing to be processed that I have control over from the .cs page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're experiencing this in IE.

Further, I'm going to guess that it's likely that there is an image source that is invalid and so it's posting back to the root. We used to have this problem as well, and you never caught it until you watched the network traffic with something like `FireBug` or `Fiddler`. Our application used to literally just logout because of the code that existed in the `Page_Load`.

Effectively what's going to happen is when an image URL fails, ASP.NET is going to receive a request at the root of the page and thus post back and wipe out the information.

Also, follow @peer advice.

Comment: I'm actually using Firefox, and even tried it on Chrome.  But yes, the first image is not coming back correctly.  This seems to be exactly what is going on.  Is there a way to stop that from happening?  I tried putting my function call in the !IsPostBack check, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Also, I do check to see if the file exists or not, but it's saying there is a file names ".jpg" which is what it is trying to use...  I've made a bandaid change for now, but hoping there is a permanent change.  The bandaid change does resolve my issue though, but could fail in other cases.

Comment: The post is 2 yrs old but it helped me find a problem on my site with a 1-pixel marketing tracker my boss wanted.  Just wanted to say thanks!

Comment: @Deverill I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

When I read you post I'm wondering why you put the variables in the session, the variables are in the context of the control/page so you should put them in the ViewState. When you put them in the Session, it will be shared over multiple pages in your site, which can result in the behavour you have. I guess that when you use the back button on your site, you will will also have unexpected behavour, which is caused by storing variables in the session instead of the viewstate.

Replace all Session to ViewState (orderBy and sort) and see if you still have the strange behavour.

Comment: I actually do this so that they are shared between pages because I do use them on other pages.  However, I am having this issue without leaving this page at all.  I'll go ahead and try it just to see, though.